# Azure - Issues With Port 22 Filtering NSG on my local machine IP

Tags: azure, azure-nsg

I am primarily an AWS developer, and testing a few things out in Azure. I have spun up a Linux VM with authentication through user/pw and am having trouble SSHing unless I allow *all* sources in my NSG.

In AWS, I would simply create an inbound rule on my SG allowing for port 22 traffic on myip/32. I thought perhaps it's because I had IpV6 enabled, however even after I disabled it I am out of luck.

Other debugging steps I've took is to add larger CIDRs in my NSG such as 172.0.0.0/8 which should be covering my local machine.. however still a time-out. I'm allowing all ports and all protocols, only trying to filter the source IP.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same process with the NSG, but from experience some ISP and big companies NAT there IP so much that the IP you get from [whatmyip site](https://ipinfo.io/) is not the actual communication IP.

Example:

[image: Image 1]

Comment: That was it. It looked like the IP I was getting from IP config was not my public IP, thus I was adding the wrong rule. Glad to know I'm not crazy and that the process is similar in Azure!